# Pass JSON Object IN ANGULAR DATATABLE

Tags: angularjs

How to pass

```
var userData=[{'name':'userName','Address':'Address'}]
```

i have to pass this userData object to DTOptionsBuilder.withSource()
it give me error . can anyone tell me how to pass this

```
  vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.withSource('data.json')
```

Comment: Why is part of your title RANDOMLY CAPITALIZED?

Comment: What is console error?

Comment: thanks for comment . But now i resolve it by bellow comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use .fromSource as it always will do an ajaxUrl request. But you can use .fromFnPromise() instead. Put your JSON into a function which returns an deferred.promise.

```
 DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function() {
        return data;
    })
```

Comment: My Pleasure as always